# Extracting words/phrase followed by a phrase

Tags: python, extract, phrase

I have one text file with a list of phrases. Below is how the file looks:

Filename: `KP.txt`

[image]

And from the below input (paragraph), I want to extract the next 2 words after the `KP.txt` phrase (the phrases could be anything as shown in my above `KP.txt` file). All I need is to extract the next 2 words.

Input:

```
This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wanted to know the exchange policy at Noriaqer hardware services.
```

In the above example, I found the phrase `" I wanted to know"`, matches with the `KP.txt` file content. So if I wanted to extract the next 2 words after this, my output will be like `"exchange policy"`.

How could I extract this in python?

Comment: I would recommend you check out https://spaCy.io … walk through their tutorials and you’ll have this solved easily. In addition to having more ideas on what you’re really trying to get at.

Comment: Are you trying to build an autocomplete algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Please don't post text as an image. This renders your post inaccessible to search engines and many people with disabilities, just to name a few of the many reasons not to take this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to read the input file into a list, it can be done with some help from regex.

```
>>> wordlist = ['I would like to understand', 'I wanted to know', 'I wish to know', 'I am interested to know']
>>> input_text = 'This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wanted to know exchange policy at Noriaqer hardware services.'
>>> def word_extraction (input_text, wordlist):
...     for word in wordlist:
...         if word in input_text:
...             output = re.search (r'(?<=%s)(.\w*){2}' % word, input_text)
...             print (output.group ().lstrip ())
>>> word_extraction(input_text, wordlist)
exchange policy
>>> input_text = 'This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wish to know where is Noriaqer hardware.'
>>> word_extraction(input_text, wordlist)
where is
>>> input_text = 'This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I\'d like to know where is Noriaqer hardware.'
>>> word_extraction(input_text, wordlist)

>>>
```

1. First we need to check whether the phrase we want is in the sentence.  It's not the most efficient way if you have large list but it works for now.
2. Next if it is in our "dictionary" of phrase, we use regex to extract the keyword that we wanted.
3. Finally strip the leading white space in front of our target word.

**Regex Hint:**

- (?<=%s) is look behind assertion.  Meaning check the word behind the sentence starting with "I wanted to know"
- (.\w*){2} means any character after our phrase followed by one or more words stopping at 2 words after the key phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I Think natural language processing could be a better solution, but this code would help :)

```
def search_in_text(kp,text):
    for line in kp:
        #if a search phrase found in kp lines
        if line in text:
            #the starting index of the two words
            i1=text.find(line)+len(line)
            #the end index of the following two words (first index+50 at maximum)
            i2=(i1+50) if len(text)>(i1+50) else len(text)
            #split the following text to words (next_words) and remove empty spaces
            next_words=[word for word in text[i1:i2].split(' ') if word!='']
            #return  only the next two words from (next_words)
            return next_words[0:2]        
    return [] # return empty list if no phrase matching
```

```
#read your kp file as list of lines
kp=open("kp.txt").read().split("\n")
```

```
#input 1 
text = 'This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wanted to know exchange policy at Noriaqer hardware services.'
print('input ->>',text)
output = search_in_text(kp,text)
print('output ->>',output)
```

```
input ->> This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wanted to know exchange policy at Noriaqer hardware services.
output ->> ['exchange', 'policy']
```

```
#input 2
text = 'Boss was very angry and said: I wish to know why you are late?'
print('input ->>',text)
output = search_in_text(kp,text)
print('output ->>',output)
```

```
input ->> Boss was very angry and said: I wish to know why you are late?
output ->> ['why', 'you']
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```py
with open("KP.txt") as fobj:
    phrases = list(map(lambda sentence : sentence.lower().strip(), fobj.readlines()))

paragraph = input("Enter The Whole Paragraph in one line:\t").lower()

for phrase in phrases:
    if phrase in paragraph:
        temp = paragraph.split(phrase)[1:]
        for clause in temp:
            print(" ".join(clause.split()[:2]))
```

Comment: Please explain how your solution solves OP's issue.

Comment: It is working Kunal, thanks. One more doubt, what if I wanted to extract more than 1 phrases that exists in the input texts, for ex:

"This is Lee. Thanks for contacting me. I wanted to know exchange policy at Noriaqer hardware services. I am interested to know other policies as well"

here, we want to extract "exchange policy" (because of 'I wanted to know') and "other policies" (because of 'I am interested to know')

Comment: @Veera it will work for all the phrases that exists in KP.txt , you can try it with that just confirm desired phrases exists in KP.txt, .

Comment: @Luke according to me code is quite simple and anyone with undestanding of basic operations on list and string slicing can understand it quite easily that's why it is here as it is,

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.